# Get CSS dropdown menu option name in Django

Tags: css, django

I am trying to create a drop down menu in CSS and get the selected option's value in Django for processing. How can I accomplish this? I tried my code with a textbox HTML and was able to get data using request.get function but how can I accomplish this using CSS dropdown menu.

Sample CSS (W3 schools):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyPage</title>
</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="someurlwhichhasaviewattached" name="Linke">XXX</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>



</body>
</html>
```

if user chooses XXX, How can i retrieve it in background?

Comment: You can attach a JS click handler to the links and make an ajax request to do whatever with the value of the link.

Comment: I have no idea about ajax

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select "XXX", then you have to use select box.
Like this :

```css
.styled select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 150px;
   font-size: 16px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   height: 34px; 
} 

.styled{
   margin: 50px;
   width: 120px;
   height: 34px;
   border: 1px solid #111;
   border-radius: 3px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="styled">
   <select>
        <option selected>Dropdown</option>
        <option>XXX</option>
        <option>Link 2</option>
        <option>Link 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Then how do i get its value in Django? like I can add an href="xyz" and view associated with that gets fired.How can I get value using the request object?